# Was the pager message from Nick Fury to Captain Marvel unnecessary?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

This question has been bugging me for a while. Maybe it is a bit overthought.

Does Nick Fury really need to send a pager message to Captain Marvel after Thanos' snap? I mean, there is only a 50% chance that Captain Marvel would survive, and if she does, she will come to know what had happened. If she cares about Earthlings, she would naturally come here for help.

So, was all this pager thing unnecessary?

Comment: I think it's a reflex action. Moreover, even if she knew she doesn't know about Team Avengers whom she can team with to fight with thanos

Comment: Besides that, it didn't seem like Fury really knew what *exactly* was going on, especially that the entire universe was effected.

Comment: I had seen the movie once in theatre and so had missed those details. I would do a bit of research and try to ask a better question. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"She'll find out eventually" isn't good enough. Earth is in trouble *right now*. Captain Marvel needs to find out *right now*. It's unclear how much time has passed between the snap and her arrival back on Earth in *Captain Marvel*'s post-credits scene, but she didn't get there immediately, so the sooner she found out, the sooner she would arrive.

As for the 50% chance, I don't think Fury knew exactly what was happening. He doesn't appear in *Infinity War* until the post-credits scene, and IIRC, there's no indication he knew about Thanos or his plan to wipe out half the universe. All he knew was that, across the planet, people had started disintegrating. He had no way of knowing that Captain Marvel herself could potentially have been affected.

Comment: "She'll find out eventually" because wherever she is, beings there would have faded or dead . 50 % thing happens throughout the universe

Comment: @ZaidSyedMMd *We* know that the plan was to wipe out 50% of life in the entire universe. Captain Marvel doesn't. She'd have to spend time investigating what happened to realise the scope of the problem and that Earth was likely also affected.

Comment: Also, even though Captain Marvel must have noticed that 50% of life was disintegrating around her, she could still have taken the pager as a hint that the phenomenon is relevant to something that's happening on Earth.

Comment: I think I'd focus more on the second-half of the answer: Fury's ignorance. Something is happening causing people to disappear, Earth may be about to be wiped out, it's clearly time to bring out the big guns.

Answer (score 5):

Wherever she is, Carol knows half of everyone disappeared. *Everywhere's in trouble*.

What Carol *doesn't* know was that Fury has a team who is fully involved and caught up on the actual root problem, and can brief her in minutes.  And they are her best hope to put her capabilities to work quickly and effectively on the problem.  In a coordinated way, with the support of others.

That, then, is the purpose of the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know if she would have come to Earth.  Carol might not have been aware of Thanos, or the Earth was at the core of events.  She could easily have guessed it was limited to the Skrulls, Kree, or wherever she happened to be at the time.  Even after she learned it was more widespread, there is no reason for her to go straight to Earth.

Similarly, no-one (at least shown on screen) told Fury what was happening.  He knew aliens attacked Earth, and that people started Dusting.  It is no major leap to guess the events are connected.  But it is a much bigger leap to guess it is universal.  Either way, Fury's focus has always been Earth, so he wants to call one of his strongest assets back.  Especially since he knows the Avengers are splintered after Civil War.

Comment: Haven't the Avengers been aware of Thanos' objective for some time?  Yes of course they are, Banner told them.

Comment: @Harper Banner told them, at the beginning of Infinity War.  We aren't told how long the movie takes, but based the stinger with Fury and Hill, at most a few days, during which most of them were very busy.